# Where is product price list column in databse?

Tags: magento2.2, sql

I am using magento 2.2.0 version .

I want to extract all products from database in mysql having price equals to one. I have entered 10 thousands of products from dashboard.

I want to know the name of sql table where they are inserting, so that I can fetch the records in phpmyadmin. Please any one know that? I am so thankful if u reply. If I find the solution I will paste answer below.

> Also i want to know the sql table name where my product Bar-code ID's
>   are safe .

Comment: __catalog_product_index_price__ is the main table of product price in Magento 2

Comment: you're right thanks , can you also tell me where i can get barcode ID's of those products in my sql table , because barcode id column is not in this table .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prices are in `catalog_product_entity_decimal` table (attribute_id=78 special_price, attribute_id=77 price, etc). Indexing updates table `catalog_product_index_price` from where prices are taken to frontend.

Actually `catalog_product_index_price`, group, tier prices are considered on frontend.

Products barcodes are in `catalog_product_entity` table.