# Catalog product price table

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm wondering where can I find the table that holds the prices for all of my catalog->products item?

Answer (score 1):

you can find them in catalog_product_entity_decimal table as the price is float attribute.

example:

find the row_id for the sku :

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE sku LIKE "%123456%"
```

find the attribute id for attribute price :

```
SELECT * FROM  eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code LIKE "%price%"
```

use the attribute id and row_id to find the price for the product :

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal WHERE attribute_id = "attribute_id you have find" AND row_id = "row id you have find"
```

you will get the price and if you want to get the price for all sku's in the catalog_product_entity table simply join them..

Answer (score 0):

Prices are in `catalog_product_entity_decimal` table (attribute_id=78 special_price, attribute_id=77 price, etc). Indexing updates table `catalog_product_index_price` from where prices are taken to frontend.

Actually `catalog_product_index_price`, group, tier prices are considered on frontend.

Products barcodes are in `catalog_product_entity` table.

And useful link for me :-

**[Where is product price list column in databse?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210825/where-is-product-price-list-column-in-databse)**

**[Magento 2: Basic Product Tables to Display on Admin & Frontend Side [SOLVED]](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140097/magento-2-basic-product-tables-to-display-on-admin-frontend-side-solved)**

Comment: Hello it's answer is helpful or not ??